# Live Admob Ads have suddenly stopped displaying in my app

Tags: ios, swift, admob

In June, Admob adverts worked perfectly and AdMob sent a letter with a verification PIN for me to verify my identity & payment details.

Around the beginning of July, nearly all live ads stopped displaying in my app. **I am still making the same number of requests**, but impressions are so low I have dropped to £0.00/£0.01 a day. **All test ads work correctly.**

This issue began around the time I renamed my app (only on the app store display), however; all links to my app in my AdMob account are correct so the name change appears to have made no difference on their front-end UI.

When I debug my app, I get a list of warnings in the output section:

1. [I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), *AppId*

***My 'GADApplicationIdentifier' value in my info.plist is the same as the 'new' app id.***

2. [I-ACS013003] User property name must start with a letter: _ap

***I am not setting any user properties, no idea what this means.***

*What have I tried?*

1. Setting up new ad units.
2. Reverting back to an older version of the app.
3. Contacted AdMob 'support' via a form. They told me my ad serving is being limited. They did not say for how long and it has been around 2/3 weeks (by 'limited', I don't think they meant completely stopped).
4. Checked for policy violations in my account; nothing is there.

*Code I use to display ads:*

I have created an 'AdMobDisplayer' class that allows me to set up and display ads; this is called by each view controller. For example, my banner ads code:

View Controller:

```
    let adMobDisplayer = AdMobDisplayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.bannerView = self.adMobDisplayer.setupAdBannerView(self.bannerView, viewController: self, adUnitId: Constants.timerTabBannerAdId)

        self.adMobDisplayer.displayBannerAd(self.bannerView)

    }
```

AdMobDisplayer:

```
    func setupAdBannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, viewController: UIViewController, adUnitId: String, bannerViewDelgate: GADBannerViewDelegate? = nil) -> GADBannerView {

        if(checkIfAdsAreDisabled()) {
            return bannerView
        }
/// Creates a new GADBannerView to be displayed in a view controller
        bannerView.adUnitID = adUnitId
        /// bannerView.adUnitID = Constants.testBannerAdId
        bannerView.rootViewController = viewController

        if let delegate = bannerViewDelgate {
            bannerView.delegate = delegate
        }

        return bannerView
    }

    func displayBannerAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        if(checkIfAdsAreDisabled()) {
            return
        }
///Creates a request and loads an advert from AdMob
        let request = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [ "My Device Id" ]
        bannerView.load(request)
    }
```

This should display a banner ad in the view. It worked when I first added adverts in, it works for test adverts, but intermittently/rarely for live adverts now.

Find the full application on my GitHub: https://github.com/AlexMarchant98/KeGal-Trainer

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this ages ago, but, my fix was to add the required 'NSAppTransportSecurity' keys into my info.plist.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/app-transport-security

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on GADBannerView in my last app and had almost similar issue, in your case you may need to generate Admob ad id, from their website.

Comment: By generating a new 'AdMob ad id', do you mean re-link my app in my AdMob account? If so, I cannot delete the app from my account so it says it is already linked when I try to link a new app.