# Google Ad Mob always says "No ad to show"

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I am setting GoogleMobileAds on an Objective C iOS app; and something unusual happens.

Even after more than a whole day, I keep getting no real ads.
The method *didFailToReceiveAdWithError* returns:

```
Error: No ad to show.
```

On the other hand all looks perfect if I use test ads.

I have done all the settings on Google Ad Mob side and the Info.plist as well.

My code has nothing special, it is the usual code for that:

```
NSString *adsUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxx/yyy";
self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc]
                   initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeBanner];
self.bannerView.adUnitID = adsUnitID;
self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;
self.bannerView.delegate = self;
[self.bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
......
```

I have found this post:
[Live Admob Ads have suddenly stopped displaying in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169995/live-admob-ads-have-suddenly-stopped-displaying-in-my-app)

and tried the suggested solution, but it does seem to work.

Beside, I can also see this message in the Xcode console:

```
2020-11-03 18:45:...[6388:3197644]  - <Google>
[I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original,
new: (nil), ca-app-pub-xxx~zzzz
```

If someone has an idea of where the problem is or could be, please let me know.

Comment: Same problem here, if you check Admob community forums you can see that there is a lot of people with the same problem. No solution yet... It is impossible to speak with Google.

Comment: OK. So I am not alone. Let us hope a solution will come soon. Thank you for answering anyway.

Comment: Same problem here. I checked everything

Comment: + 1 here. I second @MartaRodriguez: It is impossible to speak with Google. Have you people linked your app on admob console to app store? I'm waiting for 2 weeks now and the new app does not show up on admob.

Comment: I have done everything I usually do. This app is in objective C, but that should be no issue. And it does not use Firebase (unlike some of my other apps), but that should also not be a problem. Beside I also noticed that AdMob does not seem to be working very well recently on other apps either. May something is going wrong with AdMob ?

Comment: @Michel, that's probably the case. If anyone ever solves this problem please tell us here. Or maybe we should create a forum post somewhere to focus our efforts. How about?

Comment: @Daniel if you check Admob community forums you will find a lot of post about this issue (https://support.google.com/admob/thread/79758874?hl=en), but it seems that Google doesn't read his own forums... 2 weeks since our app was published and no ads yet

Comment: @Daniel I can't neither link my app in admob with the app store, it doesn't appear.

Comment: @MartaRodriguez, I've replied that topic. Let's post our updates there so that maybe google notices it

Comment: Finally today ads are showing in our app, after 17 days... We haven't changed anything. But now we can link the app in Admob, so I guess that now ads are not shown until Admob indexes the app