# AdMob ads won't show anymore on my IOS App

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have been having this issues for at least over 2 weeks. I uploaded my app and at first the ads would show and everything was fine then out of no where ads will not show anymore and analytics and shows ads are being requested but nothing is shown. I have no poilcy center issues and test ads work fine. I put the app-ads.txt which got verified and when I debug now I get this error, ""AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil)". I just made another app and now the same thing is happening. I have tried verifying my payments and everythig is seeming fine. This issue has be annoying me and have made at least another 2 posts and still no reply.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169995/live-admob-ads-have-suddenly-stopped-displaying-in-my-app)?

The accepted answer states you need to add the required 'NSAppTransportSecurity' keys into your info.plist.

Ad: Monitor your Admob and Mopub earnings using the [Motics ios app](http://motics.vivushub.com/).

Comment: No this still doesn't work. It might be linked to my account being suspended but I have no email or notification that I did that, how do I appeal?